# Posting remote CSV file data to django local server issue

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi

so I have a Raspberry Pi collecting data in a CSV file that is stored locally on the Pi. The Raspberry Pi is connected to a university network so to access the Pi remotely, I just have to be connected to the university network and have a remote project interpreter set up in my PyCharm IDE.

I've written a script that accesses the specific CSV file on the local Raspberry Pi and then posts each line of data to a local Django server. But I keep getting an error when I run it. I have tested the local Django server and script with a local CSV file on my own computer, and it worked correctly.

**The error I keep getting is**:
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /datavaluetable/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x75194050>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

My first thoughts to fix the issue were:

1. Make sure my local server was actually running (it is)
2. Disable my Windows firewall
3. Place the actual CSV file reading script onto the Raspberry Pi itself, then running it
4. Double check my project interpreter (this is set up correctly since I can access other Python files on the local Pi through PyCharm)
5. Running the django server through a Command Prompt shell and running the CSV posting script in PyCharm

I still get the same error every time and now I'm totally stuck. Could it be an issue with my system being Windows 10 and the Pi's system is Linux based? I would appreciate any help at all, thank you!

My CSV posting script:

```
import csv
import requests

csvFilePath = '/home/pi/temp/tmp.csv' # local directory of CSV on Pi

with open(csvFilePath) as f:  # opens csv file as variable f
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:  # Iterates through each row
        x = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/datavaluetable/', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, json=row)
```

Django post handling code (Views.py):

```
RESERVED_FIELDS = ['Node ID', 'System Time']

class DataValueTableList(APIView):

    parser_classes = [JSONParser]

    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []


    def post(self, request, format=None):
        datas = request.data
        nodeID = datas.get("Node ID")
        timestamp = datas.get("System Time")
        

        for key, value in datas.items(): # iterates through each key
            if key in RESERVED_FIELDS:
                continue
            else:
                DataValueTable.objects.create(sensorName=nodeID, timestamp=timestamp, valueName=key)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Is there a firewall on the raspberry pi itself?

Comment: I don't believe so. I never set up a firewall on it at least. I also checked google, and it sounds like Raspberry Pi's don't typically come with pre-setup firewalls. So it shouldn't have a firewall.